# Creating repeating event in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: calendar, outlook, google-calendar-api

Does anybody know how to create a repeating event in Outlook,  when it is not on the same day every year?

I want an event that is "Tuesday in seventh week before Easter".

Is it possible to make in any other calender and move it to Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a new instance of the AppointmentItem class in the code. Then you'll need to setup the [ReccurrencePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863458.aspx) object which you can get calling the [GetRecurrencePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868441(v=office.15).aspx) method of the AppointmentItem class. If there is no existing recurrence pattern, a new empty RecurrencePattern object is returned. You can read more about that in the [How To: Create a new recurring Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/07/outlook-recurring-appointment/) article.

If you are new in Outlook VBA, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

Create a yearly occurrence pattern, then modify each instance (that will create an exception) - RecurrencePattern.GetOccurrence() will return AppointmentItem representing the recurrence instance, modify its Start property and save the appointment.